# Anaconda install, basic usage issues

Tags: python, path, anaconda, artificial-intelligence

everyone. I installed anaconda to use python and install ai packages. I am new to high-level computer use beyond the normal GUI that windows has blessed us with.

Background: I am just starting using command prompts and am teaching myself python to use for ai with keras and tensorflow. Unfortunately, I cannot get far enough to install these packages because after I install anaconda, I get multiple errors in the command prompt. Access Denied was solved by installing for all users and running as administrator. However, I cannot use conda, and when I use pip, I get constant html errors. Nothing works. I tried adding \Anaconda3 and \Anaconda3\Scripts to PATH, but it doesn't change anything. The prompt starts by telling me that it cannot find the specified paths then kicks me over to C:\Windows\system32, but when I cd back to my \Anaconda3 directory, nothing changes. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to try?

I appreciate it. As basic as this is, rest assured I spent days struggling with this before posting.

Comment: In your terminal, what is the output of `conda -V` ?

Comment: 4.8.0 after doing conda install conda after a reinstall. It is now a different question altogether, but the I got this to work was by clicking the “not recommended” option to automatically add anaconda to path. Why is this bad?